# Remove Macros when copying sheets to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

im working on a project template for quarterly reporting where the user will complete the report with the help of some macros, and then export select sheets to a new workbook. when i copy the sheets to a new workbook, i want to remove all macros/VB code so that the person who receives the report will just get the data, and not any of the macros. what i have below copies the specific workbooks i need.

```
Dim ct
Dim strDesktopPath
Dim objWS as Object

On Error Resume Next
ct = Application.InputBox("Enter Contract Number (5555, 6666, 7777)", "Save As")
strDesktopPath = objWS.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
If ct = "5555" Then
Sheet1.Select
Sheet2.Select
Sheet3.Select
Sheet4.Select
Sheet5.Select
Selection.Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strDesktopPath & "\" & ct & " Report.xls"
End With
```

I have done research, but everything i see include something like below:

```
Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

Set objWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
            If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
                Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
                With CodeMod
                    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                End With
            Else
                VBProj.VBComponents.Remove VBComp
            End If
        Next VBComp
```

this does not work any way i try it, is there another way to remove Macros when copying sheets to a new workbook?

thank you,

Comment: what version are you using? With the latest versions, if you would save to xlsx, macro's are deleted automatically

Comment: version of Excel? im in excel 2016. i tried the xlsx and the file it saved would'nt open. am i doing something wrong?

Comment: when i do xlsx, and try to open the file, it says "Excel cannot open the file '5555 Report' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured it out. i researched saving as XLSX and found that i need to change .savecopyas to .saveas, and add a fileformat

```
.SaveAs Filename:=strDesktopPath & "\" & ct & " Report.xls", FileFormat:=51
```